# exe scheduled with task scheduler managed wrapper not executing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written following code to run exe "Unlock Users" with Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper.The task is getting scheduled in windows task scheduler and path of executable is also correct.But exe is not executing.

```
using (TaskService service = new TaskService())
{

TaskDefinition task = service.NewTask();
task.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Unlocks the screen automatically when a device is discovered";
task.Triggers.Add(new TimeTrigger() { StartBoundary = DateTime.Now, Enabled = true });
task.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
task.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(@"C:\Users\sv821590\Downloads\Unlock Users.exe", null, null));
service.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Unlock Screen", task);
```

Can someone provide any suggestions?Thanks in advance.

Comment: There could be a thousand reasons why "Unlock Users.exe" is not running--from it is not a valid executable to it does not have privilege to run to perhaps it really is running but not producing any feedback to prove it.  Try running it from the command line under the same user that runs it from Task Scheduler (presumably either the system user or user sv821590)--if it is failing, then you should at least have the error it is producing and be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: actually Unlock Users.exe is running when i double click on it.I am the user sv821590 but not running through above code through Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

The service is registrered to run ONLY if the current user is logged on. Try to change the setting in the task scheduler manually (you can set another user or tell the scheduler to run even withour the user logged on).

Try to look in the history tab of the schedule - there you will see when the job was last run.